# Is this expression idiomatic and clear? "A, B, C constitute a partition; X, Y constitute the other partition"

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57574198/10731613) a question just now.

this is an array (a group/list of numbers)

```
array([ 2,  1,  3,  6,  7,  9, 15])
```

which is divided into 2 partitions, so I said

> [2, 1, 3, 6, 7] constitute the left partition, the rest constitute the right partition

Is this expression idiomatic and clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title is more clear than the body of the question. Are "left" and "right" significant? If so, "...left partition, the rest constitute the right..." is clear. If not, your title has the better phrasing: "...a partition; ...the other partition."